# Filter and Drop rows based on a condition for a list of list column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sample of a much larger DataFrame I'm working on below

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Trial": ['Trial_1', 'Trial_2', 'Trial 3', 'Trial 4'], "Results" : [[['a', 11.0, 1, 1.0], ['b', 12.0, 0, 6.0], ['c', 2.6, 0, 3.0]], [['d', 7.3, 1, 8.0], ['e', 13.0, 0, 5.0], ['f', 8.6, 0, 3.0]],
                                                                           [['g', 9.1, 1, 1.0], ['h', 10.0, 0, 7.0], ['i', 95.6, 0, 5.0]], [['j', 6.6, 1, 1.0], ['k', 14.0, 0, 3.0], ['l', 8.1, 0, 9.0]]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

2 Queries

1. I am wanting to filter df to display the rows only where within the results columns list of lists it contains an item at index 2 == 1 and an item at index 3 != 1. In the example this filter would show only trial 2 as item ['d', 7.3, 1, 8.0] has an index 2 item equal to 1.0 but an index 3 item equal to 8.0

the desired output after filtering is below

```
Index        Trial        Results
  1         Trial_2       [[d, 7.3, 1, 8.0], [e, 13.0, 0, 5.0], [f, 8.6, 0, 3.0]]
```

2. How would I then drop the rows where the condition stated in in Query 1 is True. So dataframe would now have Trial_2 dropped and output would be

   Index        Trial        Results
   0         Trial_1       [[a, 11.0, 1, 1.0], [b, 12.0, 0, 6.0], [c, 2.6, 0, 3.0]]
   2         Trial_3       [[g, 9.1, 1, 1.0], [h, 10.0, 0, 7.0], [i, 95.6, 0, 5.0]]
   3         Trial 4       [[j, 6.6, 1, 1.0], [k, 14.0, 0, 3.0], [l, 8.1, 0, 9.0]]

I have a list comprehension below that outputs the individual items where condition is True but not sure how to apply this as a filter on df and then to use it as a condition drop rows.

```
[place for places in df['Results'] for place in places if place[2] == 1 and place[3] != 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below collects the indices of your conditions, then you can use the list of indices to either get a dataframe that matches your condition, or a dataframe that removes the rows that meets the conditions. Using apply() on each row and iterating through the list of lists. You can clean the for loop up if the first list matches the conditions you don't have to complete the for loop against the remaining lists, but I didn't go that far into the exercise.

```
idxs = [] # for collecting indices
def loop_results(x):
    for res in x['Results']:
        if res[2] ==1 and res[3] != 1:
            idxs.append(x.name) # here, .name is the index value

df_temp = df.apply(loop_results, axis=1) # apply the function to each row
idxs = list(set(idxs)) # if there are duplicates, set() will remove them

df_match = df.loc[idxs] # matched criteria
df_unmatched = df.drop(idxs, axis=0) # drops rows matching criteria
```

Comment: Many thanks, particularly for the comments included

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` on `Results` using `query_check` , which you can further modify based on any changes in the filtering logic

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Trial": ['Trial_1', 'Trial_2', 'Trial 3', 'Trial 4'], "Results" : [[['a', 11.0, 1, 1.0], ['b', 12.0, 0, 6.0], ['c', 2.6, 0, 3.0]], [['d', 7.3, 1, 8.0], ['e', 13.0, 0, 5.0], ['f', 8.6, 0, 3.0]],
                                                                           [['g', 9.1, 1, 1.0], ['h', 10.0, 0, 7.0], ['i', 95.6, 0, 5.0]], [['j', 6.6, 1, 1.0], ['k', 14.0, 0, 3.0], ['l', 8.1, 0, 9.0]]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def query_check(inp):
    for i,lst in enumerate(inp.values):
        if isinstance(lst,list):
            if lst[i][2] == 1 and lst[i][3] != 1:
               return True
    return False
    
    
df['Flag'] = df[['Results']].apply(query_check,axis=1)
```

Once you have the `Flag` column created you can filter further -

> Query - 1

```
>>> df[df['Flag'] == True]
     Trial                                            Results  Flag
1  Trial_2  [[d, 7.3, 1, 8.0], [e, 13.0, 0, 5.0], [f, 8.6,...  True
```

> Query - 2

```
>>> df[df['Flag'] != True]
     Trial                                            Results   Flag
0  Trial_1  [[a, 11.0, 1, 1.0], [b, 12.0, 0, 6.0], [c, 2.6...  False
2  Trial 3  [[g, 9.1, 1, 1.0], [h, 10.0, 0, 7.0], [i, 95.6...  False
3  Trial 4  [[j, 6.6, 1, 1.0], [k, 14.0, 0, 3.0], [l, 8.1,...  False
```